# Filter array of objects in es6 - 2 levels

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a JSON similar to the one below.

```js
[{
    "id": "13000001993",
    "title": "Most Popular",
    "answers": [{
        "id": "13000038079",
        "title": "Price",
      },
      {
        "id": "13000033122",
        "title": "Enrollment",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "13000000675",
    "title": "Support Questions",
    "answers": [{
        "id": "13000003646",
        "title": "ADMIN Chat",
      },
      {
        "id": "13000033122",
        "title": "Enrollment",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "130000005675",
    "title": "Delivery",
    "answers": [{
      "id": "13000003646",
      "title": "Cost",
    }]
  }
]
```

I want to filter the outer array and the `answers` based on `title`. Suppose if my search keyword is `Enrollment`, I want to return only the `answer` if its title matches the keyword like the following array.

```js
[{
    "id": "13000001993",
    "title": "Most Popular",
    "answers": [{
      "id": "13000033122",
      "title": "Enrollment",
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": "13000000675",
    "title": "Support Questions",
    "answers": [{
      "id": "13000033122",
      "title": "Enrollment",
    }]
  }
]
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VBzrYP

Comment: Put your codepen code here please. And what have you tried? The functions are empty...

Answer (score 3):

Because the input and output arrays are not one-to-one, and because you need to return an *altered* object and not the original object, you should probably use `reduce` to do it in one go:

```js
const findTitle = 'Enrollment';
const input=[{"id":"13000001993","title":"Most Popular","answers":[{"id":"13000038079","title":"Price",},{"id":"13000033122","title":"Enrollment",}]},{"id":"13000000675","title":"Support Questions","answers":[{"id":"13000003646","title":"ADMIN Chat",},{"id":"13000033122","title":"Enrollment",}]},{"id":"130000005675","title":"Delivery","answers":[{"id":"13000003646","title":"Cost",}]}]

console.log(
  input.reduce((a, obj) => {
    const answers = obj.answers.filter(({ title }) => title === findTitle);
    if (answers.length > 0) a.push({ ...obj, answers });
    return a;
  }, [])
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function for search `answer` in array of questions.

```js
var data = [{"id":"13000001993","title":"Most Popular","answers":[{"id":"13000038079","title":"Price",},{"id":"13000033122","title":"Enrollment",}]},{"id":"13000000675","title":"Support Questions","answers":[{"id":"13000003646","title":"ADMIN Chat",},{"id":"13000033122","title":"Enrollment",}]},{"id":"130000005675","title":"Delivery","answers":[{"id":"13000003646","title":"Cost",}]}]

function searchByAnswer (search_key) {
  var serach_result = null;
  
  data.forEach((question) => {
    var finded_answer = null;

    if (question.answers && question.answers.length) {
      finded_answer = question.answers.find((answer) => {
        return answer.title.match(search_key) !== null;
      });
      
      if (finded_answer)
       search_result = finded_answer;
    }
  });
  
  return search_result;
}
```